# Is safe to rely site security on $_SESSION?

Tags: php

I always set several vars on $_SESSION array to control access on my sites, but I would like to know if this is a safe solution or there would be something better than:

```
($_SESSION['admin'] == 1) ? take_control_of_my_site : get_back;
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check for another name.

Comment: That really depends on how $_SESSION['admin'] is being set in the first place and if you are using SSL. There are so many resources on the web about this and even a great deal of other questions that answer this in great detail.

Comment: @nathanhayfield how would the name of the variable make it more or less secure?

Comment: @nathanhayfield that's just really bad advice. Security does not come from code that's confusing to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Session data is maintained on the server side. You can rely on the data as long as

- Your server is secure
- You carefully validate any data that you place into the session.

Comment: Session IDs are stored on the client side, any user with access to the session token (for example, from an XSS attack) has access to them (Unless HTTP only cookies are used, and even then, it's not perfect). Not saying your answer is wrong, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum See my (slightly) revised answer. While it is true that the ID is available to the user, the data is not. It is the developers responsibility to ensure that he relies on the data, not the identifier.

Comment: Well, if a site will have a login screen I always do by HTTPS, and I validate this data against a database, so I think I have this covered. The real question is: Can someone alter the $_SESSION var in any way from cliente side? I think this is not possible.

Comment: HTTPS does not cover you against XSS, for one, consider setting your cookies to be httponly http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: @IkerVázquez To answer your question, no, a user can not alter your PHP (including `$_SESSION`) as long as you sanitize and secure your inputs, all PHP is processed before in even gets to the users browser

Answer (score 2):

Session is safe. Even the name of a session variable is safe and choosing another name will not increase security.

The problem in PHP is the session mechanism. It uses files by default which can slow down your site considerably and scales very poorly, and can potentially be insecure hence the suoshin php patch.

Using sessions from a database back end is much more secure, scales well, and keeps your session data safe (relies on database based security). If a hacker has your database, sessions are the least of your worries as they probably have all your password hashes as well.

Comment: If a password has the file system sessions they also have access to your site's source code, which gives them the database and everything else too.

Comment: Not necessarily. There are methods of keeping database credentials outside of the source code (apache ENV variables). You can also use strict ownership on source code files, and keep session files and source code separate (which is usually default). Finally, using suoshin the session files are no longer plain text and encrypted. They are however slow.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are not inherently unsafe. There are risks, but they can be mitigated.

It is good to be aware of the risks, so that you can learn how to avoid them, but the one thing you shouldn't do is avoid using sessions altogether because of them. Sessions are a well-established tool, and used properly they are perfectly safe and secure.

In fact, it's pretty hard to write a useful web site that doesn't use some kind of session. If you don't use the built-in one, then you'll end up writing your own -- and in most cases, that really *is* a security risk. (I know of programmers who have become obsessed with the security risks of sessions, and ended up implementing far less secure solutions simply because they didn't want to use sessions).

It's worth pointing out that recent versions of PHP have made *huge* strides forward in terms of security. There were a number of features in old PHP versions that were genuinely bad for security; recent versions of PHP have made big efforts to deprecate and remove these bad features. You will note that sessions are not in that list. They haven't needed any significant security work. This should tell you all you need to know.

Sessions are stored by default on the server in plain text. This shouldn't be a problem, unless your server can be accessed by unwanted users. If this is the case, then your security is probably already shot, so it's not really an issue, but in the rare occasion that you might be worried about that, it is possible to get PHP to provide session encryption via the [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) function.